# performance issue in retrieving data from a varbinary(MAX) field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

how i can improve the performance of the sq statement which contains Varbinary(Max) datatype

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [EmpID] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [SrNo] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [FileName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [D1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [D2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Data] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmpID] ASC,
    [SrNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

the Select Query takes around 2 to 3 seconds to select a single record with 
Data

Checked Indexing of the Table

Comment: If you are selecting for a specific empid and srno, I don't see how much more one can optimize a simple select. Your data is perhaps large? A gigabyte doesn't get transferred in a millisecond of course. In any case, for us to be able to give more insight, please include the actual query in your question along with an indication of the size of the data being selected.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052477/transactionscope-deadlocked-issue-in-concurrency   the main reason for the deadlock is time require to insert/delete operation on Table_1. is there any other way to solve my problem

Comment: Nowhere in your question do you mention about a deadlock or any other circumstances that may shed some insight into the problem you describe in this question.